# How to add on delete cascade and on update restrict using phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, foreign-keys

I want to add '`On delete cascade and on update restrict'` on foreign keys through *phpmyadmin* user Interface instead of executing query.

I generally use *Heidisql* control panel for doing these actions. And now I'm having hard time doing the same on *phpmyadmin*.

Any idea?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

In the tab where you define the **table structure**, you get the list of columns and their properties and underneath that there should be a link "**relation view**", between "print view", and "propose table structure."

That's where you want to go, but you have to have created the index on both tables already.
Also, you might want to make sure you're using mysql's innoDB storage engine.

Edit : An image is worth 1000 words :
[image: highlighted a few buttons in phpmyadmin interface]

Answer (score 21):

Cimbali's answer worked for me, but things were placed a little differently, so in case you're also looking for the "relation view" link, try looking there:
[image]

It should take you there:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Key fact:

1. Both table must be have innodb storage engine.
2. The datatype and length should be same in both table.
3. The field in 2nd table should be created as index.

Hope it will help someone...